# change state in react within 1 second without using setTimeout() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do you change the state in React within 1 second, without using `setTimeout()` method in `this.setState({})` method call?

Comment: Why do you want to do it?

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) that you have.

Comment: Format code, fix grammar, add javascript tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setInterval method.
Clear Interval after using.